# My custom marker on my google map wont show

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-api

I want to use an image(.jpg) that I have as a marker instead of the default marker/pin on my Google map. But the image won't show. There are lots of the same questions on this forum but none of them has helped me.

As soon as I take away the icon attribute from `google.maps.Marker` object the default marker shows. So that indicates that it somehow can't find my image... right?

Even when I hardcode the following link
https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png
that marker image shows. But not the one I have locally in my project.

```
var map = null;
        var mapHub;
        var markers = [];
$(function ()
        {
            mapHub = $.connection.myHub;

            //Start the hub
            $.connection.hub.start(function ()
            {
                //Get the current location from the browser
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position)
                {

                    //Create the map element on the page.
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        center: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
                        zoom: 15
                    });

                    //Add marker of current position to map
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude},
                        map: map,
                        icon: '~/Images/MapMarkerIcon.jpg'
                    }));
                });
            });
});
```

Comment: Check in the network tab in chrome dev-tools whether the image is successfully fetched or not

Comment: check for the correct path

Comment: i have already tried entering the full path starting from c drive and doesn't work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work can you please clarify what you mean? Is the image found or do you get a 404 status code? If you don't then do you get any errors at all? Also for testing purposes try placing your image at the same directory level as your js file; does it appear when you use `icon: 'MapMarkerIcon.jpg'`?

Comment: when i say it does not work i mean the marker does not show at all on the map. I dont get any error message at all. Not even in the web browsers f12 tool

Comment: my js code is not in seperate js file my js code is within a view(cshtml file) iam using asp.net mvc. But i did try put the image on the same directory level but the icon does still not show @evan

Comment: Thx i see, so you do find the image, it just doesn't show up? Do you get the default marker image instead? Can you share your custom image, what does it look like, what's its size?

Comment: I dont get the default image instead. It does not show anything.If i have a label on the marker, the label shows. But thats it. I dont think it fins my image because if i hardcode the link i have written in my intiial question, that image works. @evan

Comment: How do i attach the image? The image exists locally on my computer. the image size is 395 x 247. But I've gotten to know that the image should be adjusted automatically to a marker size. Is that true?

Comment: You can e.g. create a sandbox and upload your local image there, or use imgur. The marker's custom icons are not automatically reduced in size. Check out [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pobabiwigu/edit?html,output) in which i've set the marker's icon to a random image sized 395x247 i've just found on Google. Then try uncommenting the size property.

Comment: @evan okej it dont seem to be a size problem i have tried reducing the size the way you customized your size in the jsbin link. Do you have any other ides?

Comment: @RobelHaile Heya, okay so at this point I think you're gonna have to share your custom image itself as well as your files so that I can reproduce this on my end. You can share them via drive link or in e.g. codesandbox / stackblitz.